# Constant reference to void* pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, static, reference, constants

I want to alias a void* variable so I can use it with another name. This would mean I could set pointer (p) to something, and the aliased variable (pp) would also be set to same adress.

For instance:

```
class foo {
  private:
    static void* p; //I just happen to need this for static variable
    static const void*& pp;
};

//in cpp:
const void*& foo::pp = foo::p;
```

GCC is complaining:

> error: invalid initialization of
>   reference of type 'const void*&' from
>   expression of type 'void*'

Comment: Your declaration does not match your definition: the former is of type `const void*&` (reference to pointer to const void), whereas the latter is of type `const void*& const` (constant reference to pointer to const void), neither of which are compatible with "pointer to void".

Comment: Adam Rosenfield: whoops, that was typing error. Actual code is 'const void*&' and is still error.

Comment: Can you even have a static member that is a reference?  Also, I would advise you to think again why you need to use a void pointer in the first place.  This is usually an indication of a bad design.

Comment: @Dima: My other static references work fine. Void pointer is actualy the best way to do what I'm doing.

Comment: You modify your question then downrate people who had answered what you originally posted?

Comment: Your code is invalid for the reason I have stated. My original answer told you code that is allowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are trying to do, i.e. set a const void* & to point to void* seems like it should be legal and harmless enough, but it isn't, and it is illegal for a good reason. Remember that a reference is just an alias to what it is referencing.

Say we could do this:

`const void* & foo::pp = foo::p;` // illegal as we will see what it leads to

Now suppose that I have this:

`const char *x = "Hello world";`

As foo::pp is a pointer to const I can point it to x thus:

`foo::pp = x;` // legal as I can point a const void* to const memory

but p now also points to x because pp is a reference to p.

So now I could do this:

`memset( foo::p, 8, 'X' );`

which should of course be illegal as I am trying to modify x which is const.

That is why what you are trying to do is not allowed.

`void * const& foo::pp =  p;` would be allowed

Answer (score 1):

`const void *&` is interpreted as a reference to a const void pointer, while I think what you want here is a const reference to a void pointer. Try this instead:

```
void * const &foo::pp = foo::p;
```

Comment: I think you have it backwards. const void*& should be a constant reference to a non-constant void. Your code won't let me change foo:pp.

Comment: @Pepe: Yes, you can't change `foo::pp`. If you want to be able to change it, then why do you need a `const` at all? Just make it `void *&foo::pp = foo::p`.

Comment: you cannot change a reference to point to another object. You are very vague about what you actually want then go giving -1 to people who give you correct answers.